# Add unrelated collections in rabl

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I have an employee controller which includes designation and department. Each one is separate model so i can access each api in the client side to fill each drop down. I need like view model concept in ASP.NET MVC.

For this i read work around like return 2 collections in one json object. But i am confused in the rabl file.

My controller code is below;

```
  def employee_masters
    @designations = Designation.all
    @departments = Department.all

    respond_with @designations
  end
```

and my existing employee_masters.rabl is

```
collection :@designations
attributes :id, :name
```

please guide me how to change my rabl and controller code to achieve the behaviour. My expected json is below

```
{
    "designations": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Program Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Project Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Tech Lead"
        }
    ],
    "departments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "IT"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Support"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Finance"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Modify:**

I read [this](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/319) and got some idea. I created a class like below

```
class EmployeeViewModel
  attr_accessor :departments, :designations

  def initialize(departments, designations)
    @departments = departments
    @designations = designations
  end
end
```

My controller code is

```
def employee_masters
    @designations = Designation.all
    @departments = Department.all

    @employee_view_model = EmployeeViewModel.new(@departments, @designations)

     respond_with @employee_view_model
  end
```

And my rabl is

```
object @employee_view_model

child :departments do
  extends 'api/v1/departments/show'
end

child :designations do
  extends 'api/v1/designations/show'
end
```

Here shows error as **Template::Error (undefined method `departments' for #<#:0x00000003872168>):**

But when i change **respond_with @employee_view_model** to simply **render :json => @employee_view_model**  it worked well and return the json. Please help to rectify rabl error

Comment: Does it need to be a object at the top level?  After reading through the docs, you can pass an array to collection like `@collection [@designations, @departments]`

Comment: @Anthony thanks. I updated my findings now please help to solve rabl issue

Comment: thanks friends. I finished by changing object @employee_view_model to object :@employee_view_model